# UIDatePicker and previous view

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uidatepicker

As with the settings page, I have a UI that displays a list of parameters, one of which is a date. When the user presses the row containing the date, a controller displaying a UIDatePicker is pushed.

What is the best way to update the table row with the selected value of the UIDatePicker when the user presses the back button to go back to the list of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

How about: have the picker's controller tell the table view's controller about the update (assuming that they're not already the same object), and have that controller call [reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:) on the table view itself.

Or is your question, how do you get the controllers to talk to each other?